# HttpUrlConnection POST issue

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

Ok so when i try this on the browser I'am able to insert the params in the table people.

```
http://example.com/webservice/?value=[{
  "table": "people",
  "operation": "insert",
  "params": [
    {
      "age": 8,         
      "name": "john",
      "last_name": "johnson"    
    }
  ],
  "transactionCompleted": true
}]
```

How can I do this with Java is my question and Where do I put the boolean value of transactionCompleted ?

```
 public  void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


   int age = 30;
   String name = "john";
   String lastName = "johnson";
        URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/webservice/?value=[{\"table\":\"people\",\"operation\":\"insert\"}]");

    Map<String,Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    params.put("age", age);
    params.put("name", name);
    params.put("last_name", lastName);

    StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
    for (Map.Entry<String,Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
        if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append(',');
        postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        postData.append('=');
        postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
    }
    byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

    Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    for ( int c = in.read(); c != -1; c = in.read() )
        System.out.print((char)c);
}
```

And if I want to implement this in Android, what needs to be changed.

Comment: Uh, don't put JSON in the query string.

Comment: I used it when GET and it was working fine

Comment: Sure, it can work fine, but it's ugly.

Answer (score 0):

try this code,

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    try {
        // create connection
        URL urlToRequest = new URL(serviceUrl);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlToRequest
                .openConnection();

        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);

        switch (headerType) {
            case 1:
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept",
                        "application/json;odata=verbose");

                break;

            default:
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);


                String inputdata = "";
                if (properties != null) {
                    inputdata = properties.getProperty(Constant.ID);
                }


                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept",
                        "application/json;odata=verbose");

                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
                        Integer.toString(inputdata.getBytes().length));

                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "application/json;odata=verbose");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Auth-Token", "e1cb16d0-751c-4485-ad83-b69e848fcdf3");
                urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + cookie);

                DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
                        urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(inputdata);
                dataOutputStream.flush();
                dataOutputStream.close();

                break;
        }

        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(100000);
        // handle issues
        statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        if (statusCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED) {
            Log.d("URL Data ", "HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED");
        } else if (statusCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            Log.d("URL Data ", "HTTP_NOTOK " + statusCode);
        }

        // create JSON object from content
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
                urlConnection.getInputStream());
        data = getResponseText(in);
       }
```

work for both get, and post method.
All you need to do is create a json object of your input data, and write it on Property object, like this -

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("UserId","Deepak");
Property p = new Property();
p.put(Constant.ID,obj.toString();
```

Comment: where do I add the parameters?

Comment: what about `"transactionCompleted": true` part in the url ?

Comment: JSONObj params = new JSONObj();
params.put("age",8);
params.put("name","john");
params.put("last_name","johnson");
JSONArray paramArr = new JSONArray();
paramArr.put(params);

JSONObj obj = new JSONObj();
obj.put("table","people");
obj.put("operation","insert");
obj.put("params",paramArr.toString());
obj.put("transactionCompleted",true);

JSONArray finalArr = new JSONArray();
finalArr.put(obj);

Property p = new Property();
p.put(Constant.ID, finalArr.toString());

Comment: follow above comment, to create json of your input data

Comment: thanks for code example, but I can't just copy and paste it in my app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96719/discussion-between-kinsell-and-trush).